# real-time calculation using moment.js

Tags: javascript, html, date, momentjs

I'm trying to set up a real-time calculator for due dates using a range input. I've managed to get the range as a user slides it up or down using a basic js script. But rather than adjust due dates accordingly, it continues to subtract again and again.

So if it's due on December 1st, 2020, and the user says it will take 15 days to complete, it should be started on November 15th. If the user changes it to 10 days, it should be started on November 20th. But the numbers continue to be subtracted. I'm sure there's something I'm missing that's preventing it from recalculating each time as it should. Any help would be much appreciated!

index.html

```
<label for="q2">How many days will it take to complete the Literature Review?</label> 
<input type="range" id="litTime" name="litTime" min="0" max="50" oninput="calcTime(this.value)">                             
<span id="litDue"></span> 
<p id="litDueDate"></p>
```

dates.js

```
const dueDate = moment('01-12-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY') ;

function calcTime(litDue) {
document.getElementById("litDue").innerHTML = litDue + " days.";
document.getElementById("litDueDate").innerHTML = "This means you need to start the Literature Review by: " + dueDate.subtract(litDue, 'd').format('MMMM Do YYYY');
}
```

Comment: Each time you subtract days it changes the value of *dueDate*, so the next subtraction uses that date and subtracts further, etc. Instead, copy *dueDate* and subtract from that so you modify the copy, not the original date. Something like `moment(dueDate).subtract(...)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `moment.subtract()` method modifies the original object. So, if that's not what you want, make a copy and call `subtract()` on that copy in order to keep the original moment object unchanged. Like so:

```js
const dueDate = moment('01-12-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY') ;

function calcTime(litDue) {
document.getElementById("litDue").innerHTML = litDue + " days.";
document.getElementById("litDueDate").innerHTML = "This means you need to start the Literature Review by: " + dueDate.clone().subtract(litDue, 'd').format('MMMM Do YYYY');
}
```